# PayPal Schedule Random Recurring Payments In One Batch

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

PayPal newbie.  Is there a way to schedule multiple (somewhat random) payments with the PayPal Rest API?   The application I'm building has a weekly fee for participation in an activity.    The caveat is that some weeks are canceled due to holidays or other unforeseen reasons.

So, for a given month like September 2015, a customer may want to pay for the entire month of "valid dates" in that month.  I may need to schedule the following payments:
9/1/2015, 9/8/2015, 9/15/2015, and 9/29/2015.  (skipping 9/22/2015).
At this point, I do not see this capability with recurring payments.  Maybe a transaction with a future billing date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [classic API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/) for now.  It's still much further along than REST.

You could use [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) or you could use [Express Checkout](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/overview-ec.pdf) and/or [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/) with [reference transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/).

If you happen to be working with PHP this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the API calls to get that done very quick and easy for you.